# compare two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have two arrays like this. first array is `customFields` and  length is 2

```
var customFields = [  
   {  
      "$$hashKey":"object:259",
      "fields":[  

      ],
      "id":0.84177744416334,
      "inputType":"number",
      "labelShown":"item",
      "type":"textBox",
      "value":"222222"
   },
   {  
      "$$hashKey":"object:260",
      "fields":[  
         "as",
         "dd",
         "asd"
      ],
      "id":0.51091342118417,
      "inputType":"",
      "labelShown":"labels",
      "type":"selectBox",
      "value":"dd"
   }
]
```

second one is `field` and length is 3

```
var field = [  
   {  
      "fields":[  

      ],
      "id":0.84177744416334,
      "inputType":"number",
      "labelShown":"item",
      "type":"textBox"
   },
   {  
      "fields":[  
         "as",
         "dd",
         "asd"
      ],
      "id":0.51091342118417,
      "inputType":"",
      "labelShown":"labels",
      "type":"selectBox"
   },
   {  
      "fields":[  

      ],
      "id":0.32625015743856,
      "inputType":"text",
      "labelShown":"sample",
      "type":"textBox"
   }
]
```

both arrays are dynamic and i need to compare these arrays by `id` fields and add missing objects to `customFields` array from `field` array. how can i do this without 2 for loops looping inside one another. what is the most efficient way. thank you !!!!

Comment: Basicly you can't achieve this with a single iterator. No matter which iteration feature you're going to use, you always will need nested methods to iterate a nested structure.

Comment: Are the objects always in the same order?

Comment: As i expected, map and reduce answers are coming... :) Anyway, one way or another, you will have loops, under the hood. Nothing wrong with two ordinary, explicite, loops, imho. :)

Comment: thing is arrays can contain large no of object and i'm worried comparing and adding objects one a another take some significant time

Comment: Try to use [lodash](https://lodash.com), `_.merge` can do this, or you can combine with `_.uniqBy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `find()` to get desired result.

```js
var customFields = [{"$$hashKey":"object:259","fields":[],"id":0.84177744416334,"inputType":"number","labelShown":"item","type":"textBox","value":"222222"},{"$$hashKey":"object:260","fields":["as","dd","asd"],"id":0.51091342118417,"inputType":"","labelShown":"labels","type":"selectBox","value":"dd"}];
var field = [{"fields":[],"id":0.84177744416334,"inputType":"number","labelShown":"item","type":"textBox"},{"fields":["as","dd","asd"],"id":0.51091342118417,"inputType":"","labelShown":"labels","type":"selectBox"},{"fields":[],"id":0.32625015743856,"inputType":"text","labelShown":"sample","type":"textBox"}]

var result = field.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var f = customFields.find(el => e.id == el.id)
  r.push(f ? f : e)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks bro. if i understand correctly total and current value passed from reduce method. but can u clarify what happen inside `find` method

Comment: Sure, it is looking for element in customFields that has same id as current element in field or `e`. And if it finds it it returns that element or in this case its object

Comment: nice.  this is the first time i seen `=>` operator used to assign value in javascript. well first time for everything

Comment: That is ES6 arrow function, you can change that with regular function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133975/discussion-between-sachila-ranawaka-and-nenad-vracar).

Answer (score 1):

You can use native higher order functions such as map and reduce.

Sample implementation using lodash is here. https://github.com/rbs392/object-deep-diff/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without nested loops. First a lookup table is produced containing ID's of the `customFields` array. Next the `field` array is traversed and each missing object is appended to `customFields` array. Lookup table is also updated to take care of possible duplicates.

```
var lut = customFields.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.id;
});
field.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (lut.indexOf(obj.id) == -1) {
    customFields.push(obj);
    lut.push(obj.id);
  }
});
```

As noted in comments, my first proposition hid complexity in `indexOf`.

Here's an alternative approach that relies on object properties for ID lookup, which is likely better than linear search. `lut` maintains an association from ID to `customFields` array index.

```
var lut = customFields.reduce(function(t, obj, i) {
  t[obj.id] = i;
  return t;
}, {});
field.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (undefined === lut[obj.id]) {
    lut[obj.id] = customFields.push(obj) - 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: What if customFields is larger than fields...?

Comment: OP didn't specify the case. This just adds _missing_ entries to `customFields`, regardless of whether there's entries in `customFields` that don't exists in `field` array.

Comment: `indexOf` is the nested iteration in this code ; ).