# How to make similar movie through pipes

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm works at own movie project and want to find similar movies that movie correct by genre. I don't know how to make that

At the moment i created filter using pipe for similar movies and component for view that result. My json is viewed in the view format .ts i created constant. The below this i send that code for pipe and component for your review and wait your answer.

```js
export class SimilarPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: MovieModel[], filterSimilar: MovieModel): any {
    if (items == null) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(item => item.genres.indexOf(filterSimilar) >= -1);
  }
}
// Controller
function search(nameKey, myArray){
  for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].genres === nameKey) {
      console.log(myArray[i])
      return myArray[i];
    }
  }
}
getSimilarGenres() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.service.getMoviesID(+params.get('id'))
      )
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnscribe)
      .subscribe(movies => {
        const a = Object.values(movies);
        this.movie = a;
        search(a[4], this.movieList);
      });
  }

setSimilarMovies(genre) {
    this.showSimilarMovie ! = genre ? this.showSimilarMovie = genre : this.showSimilarMovie = null;
    this.store.dispatch({type: 'SIMILAR MOVIE'});
  }
```

```html
<div (load)="setSimilarMovies(genres)"  class="qazaq-video-list-items">
  <div class="qazaq-v-list-items mt-30" *ngFor="let movie of movieList">
    <div class="qazaq-v-list-i-img">
      <img src="assets/image/{{movie.img}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="qazaq-v-list-content">
      <div class="qazaq-v-tag c2">
        <span>{{movie.genres}}</span>
      </div>
      <a [routerLink]="['/movie', movie.id]">{{movie.name}}</a>
      <div class="movie-time">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o c1"></i>
        <span> {{movie.length}} </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That my html template

```html
<div class="qazaq-v-list-items mt-30" *ngFor="let movie of movieList | similar: showSimilarMovie">
    <div class="qazaq-v-list-i-img">
      <img src="assets/image/{{movie.img}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="qazaq-v-list-content">
      <div class="qazaq-v-tag c2">
        <span>{{movie.genres}}</span>
      </div>
      <a [routerLink]="['/movie', movie.id]">{{movie.name}}</a>
      <div class="movie-time">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o c1"></i>
        <span> {{movie.length}} </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: your operator `! =` is wrong, remove the space `!=`

Comment: Thanks @EthanVu, but i can not view similar movies

Comment: But i resulted my problem and i want know answers that question. Why I don't can make sort by similar genres

Comment: I see you passing `genres` in `setSimilarMovies()`,is that an array ? Inside the function  `showSimilarMovie` & `genre` , are you comparing two arrays or two objects

Comment: The `genre` is consist array genre types and list of movie is `movieList` variable and I want them comparing and viewed in the html. For Example, this url address [link](https://movies-finder.firebaseapp.com/movie/496243) where "similar movie" block and i want make that

Comment: so you comparing array of objects ?

Comment: @EthanVu yes i camparing array of objects

Comment: @ЕлдосКадыркул Correct me if I am wrong: You have one array which you need to compare and check for duplicates

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know, since `Array` and `Object` is `reference` type, so when you compare two arrays or objects in `javascript`, it not comparing the values, it comparing the `reference` :

```
[{name:'movieA'}] == [{name:'movieA'}] // always return false

// This make the code below always return true

this.showSimilarMovie != genre // always return true
```

The `indexOf` function is similar, it find the object or array **`reference`** not the values:

```
[{1:1}].indexOf({1:1}) // always return -1

//this make the code in your transform pipe always return an empty array

return items.filter(item => item.genres.indexOf(filterSimilar) >= -1); // return []
```

To find if an object exist in an array. You should compare it's property. For example your `MovieModel` have a property called `movieName`. Then the right way to find that object would look like this:

```
items.filter(item => item.genres.find(genre => genre.movieName === filterSimilar.movieName) != undefined);
```

For comparing Arrays, this is a huge topic. I suggest you visit these questions which is asked on SO:

[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

[Comparing Arrays of Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849757/compare-two-arrays-of-objects)

The main problem of the code you post is the compare methods is wrong.

I suggest you take sometime to do the research, play around with those `reference` comparing concept, than apply those to your code to see if there is further specific problems because the question now is too broad.

Hope my answer will help.

Comment: Can you that viewed i change controller and added function search but i don't can view that result